# How do you create dynamic relative source data for Pivot Tables in Excel?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a workbook that contains a bunch of pivot tables referencing different sheets in a separate workbook that I use as a template.

Every week I add to the pivot table workbook and save it in a separate folder.

When I try to add to the pivot table every week I have to update the source data for every single pivot table because it's referencing last week's template.

Example: In folder "45" I have pivot tables pertaining to my company for weeks 42-45 and the template with information pertaining to weeks 42-45. (I run reports four weeks at a time, there's too much data to keep an entire year...excel doesn't have enough lines for the information I'm dealing with)

I copy and paste that information into folder "46" add to the template so now it contains information 43-46, but the pivot table workbook doesn't update--I have to change the source data to every single pivot table to the template that contains weeks 43-46 in the "46" folder.

How do I make it so I don't have to keep updating the source data?

Comment: In regards to this:  *I copy and paste that information into folder "46" add to the template so now it contains information 43-46*  Do you copy the info to a Workbook, that contains four weeks or one workbook per week?  Please clarify.

Comment: If you store the data in a table, then when you cut and paste your new data into the table, you can just do a "refresh" on the pivot table and it should update it based on the new data.

Comment: @EEM One workbook per week and one pivot table workbook per week. So each week I basically delete a week and add a week.

Comment: @EEM For example -- Folder "45" I make a copy of it and just rename it "46," rename the "pivot table workbook", and the "data workbook" the pivot table work book is pulling from. Each folder has a pivot and data workbook with updated info. I drop a week and add the current week. I don't just keep one because there's too much information to store to keep all 52 weeks in a year. I also share the information with other people who are only concerned with 4 weeks at a time.

Comment: So folder 45 has four workbooks: two per weeks 42 to 45. Any reason for no having all the weeks in one folder, that will keep the connections for the prior 3 weeks and the template for the new week. Thus avoid the actual duplication  (having one week in four folders) and the risk of one week getting outdated after an update in one folder, not been copied to the others.

Comment: These other people, would be interested only in the current report, let's say weeks 42 to 46, or they may also be interested in weeks 40 to 44?

Comment: @EEM Folder: 11.04 - 11.10 (45) Contains: Data File (45) and Pivot File (45) ----------(Data File 45 is the source for Pivot File 45)------This pivot file contains weeks 45,44,43,42 (compare data 4 weeks at a time).

Comment: They will only have interest in the current report, if so then that's the group that you need to make available for them. I suggest to have all the weeks in one folder and a copy for others in a dedicated folder, just one folder, named something like "current". Wouldn't that eliminate the problem of moving the templates to different folders and loosing the connection?

Comment: @EEM I literally just make a copy of folder 45 and change the names to----- 11.11 - 11.17(46) and Data File (46) and  Pivot File (46) ---- drop week 42 and add 46. When i do this the Pivot File loses the source data.

Comment: @EEM I'll try that out tomorrow. Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Do try that and please let me know the outcome.

Comment: @EEM will do thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

To change the "SourceData" of all pivot tables at once, open the workbooks containing the `PivotTables` & `DataSource` and save the `DataSource` workbook with the new name, using the "Save As" method.

Suppose we have:

Folder: `C:\@SOs\@SO TEST\PivotTables SourceData - TEST\10.28 - 11.03 (44)`
with workbooks: `SOQ 64902342 PTs 44.xlsb` *(PivotTables)* and `SOQ 64902342 DATA 44.xlsb` *(SourceData)*

1. Option: Create new workbooks in same folder.

   - Copy `PivotTables` workbook and rename it `SOQ 64902342 PTs 45.xlsb`
   - To update the `SourceData`:

     - *Ensure workbook `SOQ 64902342 PTs 44.xlsb` is not open.*
     - Open `SOQ 64902342 PTs 45.xlsb` & `SOQ 64902342 DATA 44.xlsb` workbooks
     - Save `SourceData` workbook as `SOQ 64902342 DATA 45.xlsb` in the same folder
     - Save `SOQ 64902342 PTs 45.xlsb` workbook to preserve the updated `SourceData`.
   - Close `SOQ 64902342 PTs 45.xlsb` & `SOQ 64902342 DATA 45.xlsb` and move them to their new location.
     .
2. Option: Copy the entire folder then update workbooks.

   - Copy folder `10.28 - 11.03 (44)` and rename it as `11.04 - 11.10 (45)`
   - In folder `11.04 - 11.10 (45)` *(`PivotTables` in workbook `SOQ 64902342 PTs 44.xlsb` have workbook `SOQ 64902342 DATA 44.xlsb` in folder `10.28 - 11.03 (45)` as `SourceData`):*

     - Rename the workbook `SOQ 64902342 PTs 44.xlsb` as `SOQ 64902342 PTs 45.xlsb`
     - To update the `SourceData`:

       - Open `PivotTables` & `SourceData` workbooks
       - Save `SourceData` workbook as `SOQ 64902342 DATA 45.xlsb` in the same folder.
       - Save `SOQ 64902342 PTs 45.xlsb` workbook to preserve the updated `SourceData`.
     - Delete workbook `SOQ 64902342 DATA 44.xlsb`.